# Проверка элемента, перед добавлением в массив

Tags: php

Как сделать проверку, что бы животное не добавлялось в массив, если в массиве оно уже есть?

У меня не работает проверка и я в ступоре

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

$arr = [
    'African elephant',
    'Spotted hyena',
    'Snow leopard',
];

$new_arr2 = [];
$new_arr3 = [];

$final_array = [];

foreach($arr as $k){
    $new_arr = explode(' ', $k);
    array_push($new_arr2, $new_arr[1]);
    array_push($new_arr3, $new_arr[0]);

}


for($i = 0; $i < count($new_arr2); $i++){
    if (in_array($new_arr2[$i], $final_array) || in_array($new_arr3[$i], $final_array)) {
        continue;
    }
    else{
        array_push($final_array, $new_arr3[rand(0, count($new_arr2) -1)] . ' ');
        array_push($final_array, $new_arr2[rand(0, count($new_arr3) -1)] . '+');
    }

}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($final_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: вероятно жЫвотнае хочет размножацца ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо, вы хотите сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
<?php

$names = [
    'African elephant',
    'Spotted hyena',
    'Snow leopard',
];

foreach($names as $name){
    $parts = explode(' ', $name);
    $first[] = $parts[0];
    $second[] = $parts[1];
}

shuffle($second);

foreach ($first as $i => $f) $final[] = $f . ' ' . $second[$i];

print_r($final);
```

Если последние две строки заменить на

```
foreach ($first as $i => $f) $final[$f . ' ' . $second[$i]] = '';

$final = array_keys($final);

print_r($final);
```

, то убивается линейное распределение для случайности.

Comment: не заметил разницы

Answer (score 0):

**in_array** — Проверяет, присутствует ли в массиве значение ([источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php))

```
$haystack= array(
 'African elephant',
 'Spotted hyena',
 'Snow leopard',
);

$needle = 'Syberian elephant';

if (!in_array($needle , $haystack)) {
 $haystack[] = $needle;
}

print_r($haystack);

//output
Array ( [0] => African elephant [1] => Spotted hyena [2] => Snow leopard [3] => Syberian elephant )
```

Comment: не работает http://pastebin.com/RY1fiKpd

Comment: @DivMan код, написанный в ответе работает.

Comment: с циклом не работает