# Добавление уникального значения в массив

Tags: php

Почему, если добавлять элемент и с ним же склеить другой элемент, то получается повторение?

```
$arr = [
    'African elephant',
    'Spotted hyena',
    'Snow leopard',
];

foreach($arr as $name){
    $parts = explode(' ', $name);
    $first[] = $parts[0];
    $second[] = $parts[1];
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($first);
echo '<pre>';

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($second);
echo '<pre>';

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($arr);
echo '<pre>';

$new_arr = [];

$i = -1;
while (count($new_arr) < count($arr)){
    $proverka = $first[rand(0, count($arr)-1)];
    $i++;

    if (in_array($proverka, $new_arr)) {
    }
    else{
        array_push($new_arr, $proverka . ' ' . $second[$i]);
    }
}

var_dump($new_arr);
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проверка элемента, перед добавлением в массив](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639082/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2)

Comment: Кто научил вас писать такой ужасный код?! Работа с массивами не ограничивается использованием циклов. Посмотрите в сторону функций для работы с массивами.

Comment: если я буду использовать готовые функции, то ничему не научусь

Comment: Какая цель программы? Что значит "склеить"? Метод `push` добавляет элемент. Если таковой уже есть - ну и что, в массиве может быть сколько угодно повторяющихся эл-тов. Но по коду очень сложно понять, что от проги таки требуется...